# Would I be in "Blacklist" to send bulk mail by Simplenews?

Tags: emails

We have thousands of subscribers who sign up through our Simplenews. Now, we would like to send newsletter(eblast) through [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) with [Simplenews Content Selection](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews_content_selection) too all subscripbers. Will our server getting "blacklisted" by doing this?

PS: The newsletter has unsubscribe URL on footer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, your ip gets blacklisted if a couple of people click 'report spam' in the email browser.  Consider setting the SMTP on your server to use a web service such as [MailJet](http://www.mailjet.com) who have all kinds of advice on what to do and what not to do.